# How can I find and pass a cell reference into the StDev.P command in Excel 2010?

Tags: arrays, excel, stdev

I would like to pass a cell reference into the STDEV.P function in Excel, but when I do this I keep getting a #DIV/0 error.

I have two columns in Excel.  Column A contains a list of dates starting Jan-1-2012 and going to the current date.  Column B contains a list of integers.  I have over 800 rows of data and it's possible that integers in column B are repeated somewhere in the 800 rows of data.

I want to find the STDEV of an array of values in Column B.  The array is determined by a begin date and an end date.  The end user can decide which begin and end dates are to be used.  For example, if the begin date is 1/1/2015, I want to find the corresponding integer in column B for this date and pass the **CELL REFERENCE** into the STDEV formula.  I want to do the same for the end date.  The end result is a STDEV calculation that uses the array of integers determined by user supplied begin & end dates.

I've been able to find the cell location (e.g. value .332 is in cell D45) using the MATCH, INDEX and ADDRESS functions, but when I try to pass D45 into the STDEV function, I get the error.  Help!

Comment: I'm using STDEV.P but honestly I don't think it matters which one is used.

Answer (score 1):

Many users believe that an `INDEX(MATCH(...))` pair only returns a cell value in a lookup but in fact it can be used to return a cell reference without the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd)'s overhead. Two of them can even be joined with a colon to form a valid cell range to be used in any number of formulas.

[image: STDEV with INDEX/MATCH range]

The formulas in F2:H2 are,

```
=STDEV(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D2,A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(E2,A:A, 0)))    ◄F2
=STDEV.P(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D2,A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(E2,A:A, 0)))  ◄G2
=SUM(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D2,A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(E2,A:A, 0)))      ◄H2
```

I've included a simple [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) so that you can quickly verify that the method used is returning the correct cell range without doing the math on a StDev.

Of the many lookup functions, this is an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) trait. The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a) cannot be used in this manner as they are only returning the values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your start date is in D1 and your end date in D2 please try:

```
=STDEV.P(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(D1,A:A,0)&":B"&MATCH(D2,A:A,0)))
```

As long as the dates are unique it should not matter that the other values are not.

Comment: This worked!  Although when I try to break it out into its individual components, it doesn't work.  For example, I can run the MATCH functions no problem.  But when I apply the INDIRECT function to the MATCH function's results, I get a 0 (for both begin & end dates).  When I plug these values into the STDEV.P function, I get a different value than if I simply run STDEV.P and manually select the array of values to use.